# Is $\{0,1,3\}$ a proper subgroup of $\mathbb Z _ 4$ under addition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

> Is $\{0,1,3\}$ a proper subgroup of $\mathbb Z _ 4$ under addition?

I think it is not because closure property does not hold for it.

If we check, $3+3$ gives $2$ (in $\bmod 4$) which is not present in $\{0,1,3\}$.

If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: I agree with your analysis.

Comment: Where is your doubt? Do you doubt that $3+3=2$? Or that $2\notin\{0,1,3\}$?

Comment: As a further sanity check, you could invoke Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Even $1+1=2 \notin \{0,1,3\}$…

Comment: @ArthurVause This would be like shooting rockets on ants.

Comment: @Peter, you mean it would be lots of fun?

Comment: I think you ask if a set is not closed w.r.t. group operation then it does not form a group, like $3+3=2mod(4)$ so it is not closed that implies it is not a subgroup.

Comment: Perhaps the point made was that any two add to the third, unless you allow them to be the same one, which you do allow, so it's not a subgroup.

Comment: You are not wrong. Trust yourself!

Answer (score 2):

You're right.

Here's an alternative answer . . .

Since $3\nmid 4$, by [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), the set in question cannot be a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_4$.

Comment: Correct, but isn't that overkill?

Comment: Yeah, you could say that, @PaulFrost. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: In fact it's the subset of cubic ( or higher odd power)  residues.